# IE 6 7 style="overflow:auto;

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

So, I've got a problem using style="overflow:auto; on IE6 / 7 browsers. It just doesn't work there.

I've tried some jquery, but it was fail plaguins ... I can't get them work properly.

So what will you recommend to me to make overflow working for IE6,7 ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the doctype
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">`

Or not `IE6 must die soon, not later :)`

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the dimensions of the div

```
<div style='overflow:auto; width:200px; height:100px'>das</div>
```